# Is it ok to ask a new question inspired by a closed question?

Tags: discussion

Let's say Bob asks Question X on this site, but it gets closed for being too off-topic. Bob brought up some interesting dilemmas in Question X, but nevertheless Question X did not fit the standards for this site. Would it be acceptable for me to write my own question, call it Question Y, which inquires about the same dilemmas? Or would my question get flagged as a duplicate and make the moderators angry?

Case in point, [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/38513/if-a-man-seduces-a-virgin-exodus-2216-17) about Exodus 22:16-17 was closed, but nevertheless contained some food for thought. (For example, why is there no mention of a sin offering required for seduction?) I would still like to ask  my own question about this passage, even though it will be similar to (although not exactly the same as) the closed question. Am I free to post my own question asking for an interpretation on Exodus 22:16-17 as it relates to marriage?

Answer (score 4):

Closed off-topic questions are generally not eligible as targets for duplicate closures. We try to point duplicates at *open* questions. If your rehash of the question turns out to also be off-topic, it should be evaluated and closed on its own merits as off-topic. If it is sufficiently different and you make an on-topic question then that will of course stand.